# TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getState’ of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to try small redux example so I installed redux but I got this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getState’ of undefined
>
> new Provider
>   webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:24:25

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import './index.css';

const App = () => (<div>Hi </div>);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If we look inside [`react-redux <Provider />`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/Provider.js#L12)

`<Provider />` expects to be provided a `store` prop:

> ```js
> this.state = {
>   storeState: store.getState(),
>                    ^^here
>   store
> }
> ```

Hence the error.

You can create one, though, using a reducer, should be something similar to this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducer from './reducer'
import App from './components/App'

const store = createStore(reducer)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: thanks. but I dont have a reducer yet is there a way to make a blank example without reducer ?

Comment: redux state container is the `store`, and you have to create one, but in order to create one, you should pass it a `reducer` https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js#L57 as clearly indicated here. `reducer` is an integral part of the `redux` philosophy as even the name implies. Imho, so when you take `reducer` out of the equation you are no longer talking about redux, maybe you need something else. I mean if you don't want a `reducer`, why do you need `redux`, what are you going to test and `reduce` over?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a store to your provider.

If you don't have any reducer, you can add a dummy reducer.

Assume that the dummy reducer returns an empty array.

```
() => []
```

So, your code will be changed to:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'; 

const store = createStore(() => [], {}, applyMiddleware());

import './index.css';

const App = () => (<div>Hi </div>);

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add dummy store so you can use your provider.

> **Provider** needs store..
>
> if you not add this u got error... TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getState’ of undefined
>
> so add ..

const store = createStore(() => [], {}, applyMiddleware());

> so u can use like this...

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <App />
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error as I was not returning a function from store.js.

Wrong :
export const makeStore = () =>{
configureStore({
reducer: masterReducer,
});
}

Correct:

```
export const makeStore = () =>
      configureStore({
        reducer: masterReducer,
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you also need to pass the store as a parameter to the Provider object (as a value for the prop *store*), which wraps the App. You could do it this way:

At *index.js*:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import reducer from "./store/reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

At *reducer.js*:

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return state;
}

export default reducer;
```

Of course, then in the reducer you need to add whatever you want to be executed, depending of the type parameter inside of the *action* object, which is also passed as parameter into the reducer.

An example (at *index.js*):

```
const initialState = {
    counter: 0
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'INC_COUNTER') {
        return {
            ...state,
            counter: state.counter + 1
        };
    }

    if (action.type === 'ADD_COUNTER') {
        return {
            ...state,
            counter: state.counter + action.value
        };
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was because I was trying to `export default store` instead of `export const store` (despite ESLint nagging for "preferred export default" rule) -- this is similar to the answer @Sakar is mentioning.

For example: I had this, which throws the exact error message in question (WRONG):

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user,
    chat,
    email,
    invoice,
    calendar,
    permissions
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    })
})
export default store
```

This is when I receive the error asked about here in this post.
`TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getState’ of undefined`

So I changed it to this, and it works (it finds getState from redux) (CORRECT):

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user,
    chat,
    email,
    invoice,
    calendar,
    permissions
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `easy-peasy v 5.2.x`

To create a store

`store.js`

```js
import { createStore, action, thunk, computed } from "easy-peasy";
import api from "./api/posts"

export const store = createStore ({
    posts: [],
    setPosts: action((state, payload) => {
        state.posts = payload
    }),

})
```

`index.js`

```js
import { StoreProvider } from 'easy-peasy'
import {store} from "./store";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <StoreProvider store={store}>
        <App />
      </StoreProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```