# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getState') at /home/ubuntu/online-coding-judge/submissions/1466948/unit-6/sprint-4/day-3/assignments/ReactTheme/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:36:57 at mountMemo (/home/ubuntu/online-coding-judge/submissions/1466948/unit-6/sprint-4/day-3/assignments/ReactTheme/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17225:19) at Object.useMemo (/home/ubuntu/online-coding-judge/submissions/1466948/unit-6/sprint-4/day-3/assignments/ReactTheme/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17670:16) at useMemo (/home/ubuntu/online-coding-judge/submissions/1466948/unit-6/sprint-4/day-3/assignments/ReactTheme/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1650:21) at Provider (/home/ubuntu/online-coding-judge/submissions/1466948/unit-6/sprint-4/day-3/assig

i got this error and not a pass single test case can any one please help me to find out whats wrong in code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./Redux/store";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
        <Provider store={store}>

                <App />
        </Provider>


);

reportWebVitals();
```

```
import "./App.css";
import Counter from "./Components/Counter";
import Theme from "./Components/Theme";
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Theme />
      <Counter />
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { legacy_createStore as createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { counterReducer } from "./counterReducer";
import { themeReducer } from "./themeReducer";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        counterReducer,
        themeReducer,
});
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default store;
```

```
//Complete the reducer function logic inside the curly braces {}
// the theme initstate shouldbe light
import { CHANGE_THEME } from "./actionTypes";
const themeReducer = (state = "light", action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
                case CHANGE_THEME:
                        return action.payload;
                default:
                        return state;
        }
};

export { themeReducer };
```

```
//Complete the reducer function logic inside the curly braces {}
// the counter initstate shouldbe 10
import { ADD, REDUCE } from "./actionTypes";


const counterReducer = (state = 10, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
                case ADD:
                        return state + action.payload;
                case REDUCE:
                        return state - action.payload;
                default:
                        return state;
        }
};

export { counterReducer };
```

```
//DO NOT change the function names

import { ADD, REDUCE, CHANGE_THEME } from "./actionTypes";

const handleAdd = () => {
        return { type: ADD, payload: 1 };
};

const handleReduce = () => {
        return { type: REDUCE, payload: 1 };
};
const handleTheme = (theme) => {
        return { type: CHANGE_THEME, payload: theme };
};

export { handleAdd, handleReduce, handleTheme };
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import CounterValue from "./CounterValue";
import CounterButtons from "./CounterButtons";
import './counter.css'

const Counter = () => {
  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.themeReducer);
  return (
    // the following div classname should be chnaged accrding to the theme
    <div className={`counter ${theme === "light" ? "light-theme" : "dark-theme"}`} data-testid="counter">
      <h1>Counter</h1>
      <CounterValue />
      <CounterButtons />
      {/* Import CounterValue component here and DO NOT PASS anything through props, for this component */}

      {/* Import CounterButtons component here and DO NOT PASS anything through props, for this component */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { handleTheme } from '../Redux/action.js'
import './Theme.css'
const Theme = () => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const theme = useSelector((state) => state.themeReducer);

        const handleThemeChange = (newTheme) => {
                dispatch(handleTheme(newTheme));
        };

        return (
                <div >
                        <button
                                data-testid="switchToLightButton"
                                disabled={theme === "light"}
                                onClick={() => handleThemeChange("light")}
                        >
                                Switch to Light
                        </button>
                        <button
                                data-testid="switchToDarkButton"
                                disabled={theme === "dark"}
                                onClick={() => handleThemeChange("dark")}
                        >
                                Switch to Dark
                        </button>
                </div>
        );
};

export default Theme;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const CounterValue = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counterReducer);

  return <div data-testid="counterValue">{counter}</div>;
};

export default CounterValue;
```

I am getting error please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property ‘getState’ of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847624/typeerror-cannot-read-property-getstate-of-undefined)